# Отредактировать внешний вид через css или jquery но не трогая html

Tags: html, css

Изменить вид так, чтобы все серые строчки имели цвет через одну разные, причем редактировать только CSS. Если нельзя средствами CSS то хотя бы при помощи jQuery, но HTML должен остаться не изменённым. Помогите составить цвета на разных строках через одну с любым цветом, просто для примера.

http://jsfiddle.net/twxt8pvo/

```
.tb {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tb th.global {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #000;
}
.tb th.pod {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #dadada;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите

```
background: #dadada;
```

и в конце добавьте еще `css`

```
.tb>*:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red!important;
}
.tb>*:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue!important;
}
```